# How do you reference a Resource Bundle that comes from a Grails Plugin

Tags: grails, grails-resources-plugin

In my GSP I want to reference a Resource Bundle that is being defined in a plugin so I can be path-agnostic in my grails application.

In the Resources.groovy file I have:

```
modules = {
    widgeta {
        resource url: 'directives/widgeta/widgeta.js'
        resource url: 'directives/widgeta/restapi.js'
    }
}
```

In the HEAD of a GSP within my Grails App (which is correctly pulling everything in from the Plugin including Controllers and domain objects) I have this:

```
<r:require modules="widgeta"/>
```

When I try to run i get this:

> Caused by IllegalArgumentException: No module found with name
>   [widgeta]

Which makes sense because I don't see the Resources.groovy file anywhere in the plugins that are being included.

How do I either

1. automatically include the Resources file from the plugin.
2. reference the files within the plugin from my application's Resource.groovy file(s)?

Comment: Can you also add the directory structure of the plugin where the above mentioned resources reside?

Comment: Everything turns out to be setup correctly it was just that my .grails cache was out of date and didn't have the newest copy of the plugin with the <plugin-name>Resources.groovy file in it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the issue was that my 'installed plugin' was out of date. the version of the plugin which was installed into my app did not have the Resources.groovy file with the correct bundle specified. Blowing away that plugin and re-installing it (really just building again) seems to have solved my issue.